# Make windows' grouped programs to be in the most recently used order using win + number shorcut

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, taskbar, ordering

Windows groups programs together in the taskbar so that the user can access them using <kbd>win+#</kbd>. You can cycle through them by pressing the same <kbd>#</kbd> multiple times, but these programs are ordered in the most recently *opened* order. Is there a registry tweak or software that will make it most recently *used* order?

Answer (score 1):

It would have been possible in Windows 7 with `list_reverse_order` enabled in the advanced option of [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-for-windows-10-beta-version), but it no longer works for Windows 10.